# Fabric.js multiple clipping based on SVG path

Tags: jquery, fabricjs

I have a canvas with many svg paths on it, My aim is to drag and drop images on to the canvas,
I am able to do that, when an image is dropped on the canvas i want to clip the image based on the svg path where it is dropped,

I posted the same issue many times, This time i am sharing my page link to you guys, Please have a look at the js code, I don't get what is the problem there, When i clip the image with a rectangle using the ctx.rect() method that rect is not moving when i drag the image, but when i draw the same path on the canvas it is moving along with the image ?

I want to draw and drag the image inside the path where it is dropped.

Here is link to the page, I am using one sample svg file from fabricjs.com/kitchensink/ page

http://qa.newagesme.com/wyz_editor/
drag and drop an image on to the skirt of the avatar showing on the page.

Comment: I suggest that : 1. use some 2D geometry javascript to detect intersection between image and path 2. use filter to remove parts of image outside of path, so it won't display. I never tried, but for fabricjs I didn't know what we can do to solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me show you my idea, when you put an image into a path, so this path could be its filter based parameter, and if you want to move path and all inside it, using group is a way I think. Actually this image is not inside the path, but looks like it does. I really hope fabricjs can have another children tree for objects, so every children of the object could be only active inside this object, but apparently this idea is not suit for current version. I would like to try to make one, still learning fabric.js source. http://jsfiddle.net/hellomaya/kjzZR/5/

This isPointInPoly function adapted from here https://github.com/substack/point-in-polygon, and the filter creation code from fabricjs.com.

Your question is interesting, also useful in similar product.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');
var src = "http://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png";
canvas.backgroundColor = "#ccc";
canvas.renderAll();

var padding = 0;

fabric.Image.fromURL(src, function (img) {

    img.set({
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        left: 120,
        top: 20
    });

    var points = [{
        x: 185,
        y: 0
    }, {
        x: 250,
        y: 100
    }, {
        x: 385,
        y: 170
    }, {
        x: 0,
        y: 245
    }];

    var polygon = new fabric.Polygon([{
        x: 185,
        y: 0
    }, {
        x: 250,
        y: 100
    }, {
        x: 385,
        y: 170
    }, {
        x: 0,
        y: 245
    }], {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: 'black',
        stokeWidth: 1
    });
    console.log(polygon.width + ":" + polygon.height);

    canvas.add(img);
    canvas.add(polygon);
    polygon.selectable = false;

    fabric.Image.filters.Redify = fabric.util.createClass({

        type: 'Redify',

        applyTo: function (canvasEl) {
            var context = canvasEl.getContext('2d'),
                imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasEl.width, canvasEl.height),
                data = imageData.data;
            var width = imageData.width;
            var height = imageData.height;

            width = Math.ceil (img.width);
            height = Math.ceil (img.height);

            console.log (width + ":" + height);
            //console.log ("left=" + img.left + ":top=" + img.top);

            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i += 4) {
                //data[i + 1] = 0;
                //data[i + 2] = 0;
                var x = Math.ceil(i / 4);
                var y = Math.ceil(x / width);

                x = x % width;

                x = x * img.scaleX + img.left;
                y = y * img.scaleY + img.top;

                //console.log (x + ":" + y);

                if (!isPointInPoly(points, {
                    x: x,
                    y: y
                })) {
                    //alert (x + ":" + y);
                    //data[i + 1] = 0;
                    //data[i + 2] = 0;
                    data[i + 3] = 0;
                }
            }

            context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
        }
    });

    fabric.Image.filters.Redify.fromObject = function (object) {
        return new fabric.Image.filters.Redify(object);
    };

    img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Redify());

    canvas.on("object:moving", function () {
        img.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
    });

    function isPointInPoly(vs, pt) {
        var x = pt.x,
            y = pt.y;

        var inside = false;
        for (var i = 0, j = vs.length - 1; i < vs.length; j = i++) {
            var xi = vs[i].x,
                yi = vs[i].y;
            var xj = vs[j].x,
                yj = vs[j].y;

            var intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y)) && (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
            if (intersect) inside = !inside;
        }

        return inside;
    }

    //polygon.selectable = false;
});
```

Comment: Yes, This bit of code shows an other approach to clipping out the image out side the target path, But in our case, its like, the content of the canvas can be any svg documents with some paths in it, so the mask cannot be a polygon always also there can be more than one path with different shape. So instead isPointInPoly() we can use the object.containsPoint() method to find out whether the point is inside the path or not; right ?

Comment: Hi seems this is not working on rotating function.. do you have any idea on rotating function.. object:rotating